# Highcharts Pie Graph Doesn't Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to create a Pie Graph with High charts. I get all the values from the database through PHP, as well as the series, which are send to jQuery through JSON in which I parse that JSON and get it to the function that creates the graph.

```
$query = [array('name'=>'SAP', 'id'=>48), array('name'=>'EIS', 'id'=>65), array('name'=>'P2P', 'id'=>84), array('name'=>'Portal Gift Card', 'id'=>92), array('name'=>'Tenants Survey', 'id'=>74), array('name'=>'Outros', 'id'=>17)];
            $series = array('name' => 'Effort');
            $seriesData = array();
            foreach ($query as $data){
                $rslt = $this->gm->getEffortApp($data['id']);
                array_push($seriesData, array('name' => $data['name'], 'y' => $rslt));
            }
            $series['data'] = $seriesData;
            echo json_encode($series, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This are the codes that get me the data and send it to the jQuery through JSON.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var param = '<?=$graphdata['param']?>';
    asyncCall('post', '?/graphAsync/getSeries/'+<?=$graphdata['graph_id']?>,{param: param}, 'text',function(data){                                              //returns the right array to populate the graph
        var series = $.parseJSON(data);
        setChartData($('#graph'+<?=$graphdata['id']?>), '<?=$graphdata['graph_type']?>', '<?=$graphdata['graph_title']?>', 'Teste', '<?=$graphdata['graph_titleY']?>', series);
    });      
});
```

This is the code that receives all the graph data and parses the JSON string.

```
function setChartData(elem, type, title, categories, titleY, series){
elem.highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: type
    },
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: titleY
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        },
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: series,
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
}
```

This is the function that creates the graph.

The rest of the graph data comes from the controller load (CodeIgniter) and seems to be fine.

The output of the server (JSON string) is as follows:

```
[{"name":"SAP","y":9420.35},{"name":"EIS","y":2282.5},{"name":"P2P","y":218.5},{"name":"Portal Gift Card","y":203},{"name":"Tenants Survey","y":323},{"name":"Outros","y":1}]
```

And the input in the function of the series is something like this:

```
series=[object,object,object,object,object,object]
```

And each object is as follows:

```
object:[name:'something', y:*number*]
```

The graph loads empty, only with the title and the export button.
For some reason I can't post images so that's why I didn't put any image of the graph output.

thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is the jsfiddle, although for some reason I can't get it to work the way it is in localhost. That's essentially what I'm doing, but instead i'm passing the arguments through PHP variables.

Comment: Try to use series: [{ data: series }]

Comment: @SebastianBochan I just tried it, the output is the same, graph loads empty, only title apears.

Comment: Are you able to recreate your chart as live demo?

Comment: @SebastianBochan here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/4x1v54xc/1/
Not working as in the page, I don't know why. Recreated it the best I could. In my page I'm passing the arguments through PHP variables.

Comment: Look at your setChartData, you call that with 5 arguments instead of six (which are in function definition). Morever you have syntax errors. Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4x1v54xc/2/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks but I still get an array to string conversion error. What you did is correct, but since I'm calling that same exact function to two column graphs in the same page as that one. Although the values of the arguments are diferent, if I change categories the other two graphs get wrongs categories and the pie graph doesn't work with the same 'array to string conversion' although the variable is empty.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I got that fixed by doing a PHP validation and if the graph type was 'pie' I'd set the categories to a string. The graph loads now, but it's the same as before, loads with the title only, the rest is empty. I believe it's some problem with the series, but i'm doing as the fiddle, I create series in PHP, making an array with the name and pushing another array to the 'data' index, that contains the array with the name and 'y' data of each value to show. I got the code wrapped around a comment in the fiddle if you want to take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/4x1v54xc/3/

Comment: Is correct example, because seems to working fine?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I have managed to solve the problem. The problem was that I was putting the value into another variable when I should be pushing the array to that variable, which is also an array. Now it works perfectly fine, finally. Thank you so much for responding and helping me out with. Going to upload the PHP comment with the right code.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks for feedback